# Applying audit policy on multiple auditing subject or object

Tags: db2, audit

I have created a policy on execute category and I would like to know if this policy can be applied on multiple auditing subject or object. Since the execute category will generate many audit entries I would like to limit the results by applying this execute audit policy on specific user/table combination.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the audit policy created by [CREATE AUDIT POLICY](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050607.html) is database-wide, it is applied to individual objects or roles by the [AUDIT statement](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050609.html?pos=2). For example, to audit statement executions (successful or otherwise) against a particular table:

```
CREATE AUDIT POLICY allexec CATEGORIES EXECUTE STATUS BOTH;
COMMIT;
AUDIT TABLE mytable USING POLICY allexec;
COMMIT;
```

To audit statements executed by a particular role:

```
AUDIT ROLE somerole USING POLICY allexec;
COMMIT;
```

The reason for all the COMMITs is that, as the docs note, "[a]n AUDIT-exclusive SQL statement must be followed by a COMMIT or ROLLBACK statement...". See [audit policies](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0050525.html) for more information.